# Person Account RecordTypes metadata

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, person-accounts

I have Person Accounts enabled in my sandbox org. When I pull the (objects/Account.object) metadata in Eclipse I don't see any Person Account record types in Account.object. I *can* see record types associated with Business Accounts.

Bug or obvious error?

ETA: API version 35

Comment: Do you see anything like consumer recordtype on Account?

Comment: No. There's nothing person account related.